# luatex complains Cannot open the file ~/.config/font-manager/local.conf

Tags: luatex

From TeXLive-2011: luatex complains:

```
! LuaTeX error ...1/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-font-nms.lua:525: Cannot open the file $HOME/.config/font-manager/local.conf
```

where $HOME is the path of my home directory.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: is the `$HOME` environment variable actually defined (or defined correctly) on your system?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Some of your font configuration files is including a non-existent `$HOME/.config/font-manager/local.conf`, check `~/.fonts.conf` or `~/.fonts.conf.d/`. But raising an error here is too much, `luaotfload` should fail gracefully (printing a message to the log is all it should do).

Comment: @ArTourter: $HOME is correctly set (in the cited snippet, I replaced my actual home dir with $HOME).

Comment: @Khaled: The file that it says it cannot open actually exists.

Comment: Aaaaah... stracing showed: 8245  open("(MY HOME DIR)/.config/font-manager/local.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)

Comment: The reason is that lualatex opens this local.conf file several thousand times, without ever closing it, until the system refuses to open file descriptors (as seen from stracing). I consider this a bug in lualatex.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, lualatex opens ~/.config/font-manager/local.conf repeatedly, without ever closing it, until the operating system refuses to return new file descriptors.

This most likely comes from a bug in lualatex, perhaps triggered for systems with many fonts installed.

Comment: May be you have a cyclic include somewhere, putting the code into an infinite loop, that is the only way I see this happening.

Answer (score 2):

I got bitten by the same bug today, and there was indeed a circular include in the file:

```
<include ignore_missing="yes">/home/rpinson/.config/font-manager/local.conf</include>
```

Commenting it out solved the issue.